# Adding Venues to FourSquare API Without Authentication

Tags: swift3, foursquare

Im building an app using the Foursquare API and Swift and would like to know...   Under what circumstances will Foursquare allow your app to create a venue without authenticating the user?

As stated [here by Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add).  Whats does "some cases" mean ?

Adding Venues Without Authenticating Users First
This endpoint generally requires you to authenticate Foursquare users before you can add venues on their behalf. In some cases, we’ll make exceptions and allow applications to create new venues without authenticating any users.

Answer (score 1):

If your a large organization that adds or manages venues on behalf of customers (i.e. Yext) you may not want to have every user authenticate. If you have a business case for this you should probably reach out to [Foursquare directly](https://enterprise.foursquare.com/contact-us).

Comment: Im working for a startup.  Im guessing we would not qualify?  Thanks for the response.